# Struts 2 JQuery Datepicker Issue with Java.util.Date

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, datepicker, struts2

I am using Struts2 jQuery Datepicker plugin. for the tag lib, JSP, backend  i have added the following code snippet for your reference. i have used java.util.Date class for backend. Every-time i run the code it gives me error. As per my understanding struts2-jquery does not directly cast datePicker value to `java.util.Date` we need to change the dateType of startDate from `java.util.Date` to `String`. correct me if i am wrong.
any better approach for its workaround?

Using `String` everywhere in application is not the best solution as there are lots of places which i need to update and of-course Service and DAO implementation will also be affected.

Thanks in advance.

**Tag lib:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
```

**JSP datepicker:**

```
<sj:datepicker id="startDate" name="searchFilter.startDate" cssStyle=" width:110px" displayFormat="mm/dd/yy" buttonImage="images/calendar.gif"/>
```

**Java Code Backend:**

```
private Date startDate;

public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}
```

**Error:**

```
Error setting expression 'startDate' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@412acad5'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setStartDate([Ljava.lang.String;)
```

Comment: It's expecting a method with a string argument

Comment: @PranavCBalan, yeah but if you look at backend i clearly mentioned java.util.Date why it is treating String? any way forward to use java.util.Date?

Comment: sorry I'm not familiar with `struts2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution i found on internet was as i did not want to change my **Service** and **DaoImpl** classes. what i did was i defined one variable in java class of data type `String` and bind with jsp component where i was using startDate(`java.util.Date`)

```
private String startDateValue;

public String getStartDateValue() {
    return startDateValue;
}

public void setStartDateValue(String startDateValue) {
    this.startDateValue = startDateValue;
}
```

in setter method i had to define java `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` object to parse `String` value to `java.util.Date` Object.

```
final Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(startDateValue);
```